# SQLite doesn't care about `varchar` length. Is the same true for `char` length?

Tags: sqlite

When I run `sqlite3 foo.db` from cmd (Windows) and enter these commands (assuming TABLE 'test' does not exist):

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE test (id integer PRIMARY KEY, name char(1));    
sqlite> INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ('aaaaaa');
```

there are no errors. To verify,

```
//Input
sqlite> SELECT * FROM test;  

//Output
1|aaaaaa
```

Again, to verify,

```
sqlite> .schema test    
CREATE TABLE test (id integer PRIMARY KEY, name char(1)); //output
```

and the schema isn't changed.

Is there something wrong, especially with the `name char(1)` part?  For the record, I compiled SQLite3 using MinGW64 with

```
--host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw // where /mingw is included in my PATH
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

As [there is no types in SQLite](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html), the question is meaningless. All TEXT values are the same and are stored as "unlimited" (up to SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH) length strings.

Comment: What is the maximum size of a VARCHAR in SQLite? http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q9

Answer (score 1):

What you see is a [WAD](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/W/working-as-designed.html): "working as designed".

SQLite doesn't enforce the length of a char(n) or varchar(n) column *as it's declared in a CREATE TABLE statement*. But you can enforce length restrictions using a CHECK constraint.

```
sqlite> create table test (
   ...> id integer primary key,
   ...> name char(1),
   ...> check (length(name)<=1)
   ...> );
sqlite> INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ('aaaaaa');
Error: CHECK constraint failed: test
```